# Possible to use valueFrom on containerPort

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to use secrets on a containerPort?

For example:

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name: postgres
      image: testproject/postgres
      ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
```

Doing something like:

```
  containers:
    - name: postgres
      image: testproject/postgres
      ports:
        - containerPort:
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: app-secrets
              key: PGPORT
```

Tested it and it doesn't work so seeing if there is a different syntax.

I'm probably being overly cautious, but figured it would be more secure to not have the port in plain text somewhere, even though that port wouldn't be available publicly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's doable. I recommend focusing on setting up database privileges and using secrets with your database passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Just taking a step back: Why would you event want to put your containerPort into a secret?

1. Most images are pulled from a repository like Docker Hub, so the container port is known publicly for those images anyway by anyone who wants to look it up. Sure you could argue against this for custom images you have created which is not publicly accessible, and that is a fair point.
2. You're not really adding security by trying to hide the containerPort, as that runs inside your cluster and is only accessible within your Kubernetes cluster internal network.
3. Specifying the containerPort on a pod does not actually change the container port, it's for informational purposes only (basically documentation telling you what port is being used by the application running in the container).
4. You could just as easily leave the containerPort out entirely, as the container that is running in the pod exposes its required ports either way, whether you specify containerPort or not, or even if you specify the incorrect container port.  E.g. the image for NGINX is pre-configured to run on port 80, so the container running the NGINX image will be listening on port 80 regardless.  Even if you had to specify --containerPort=8080, the NGINX container would still be running and listening on port 80. Just your kubectl describe command would be giving you false info (port 8080) because your documentation (--containerPort=8080) is incorrect.

So in conclusion, I would say don't event bother trying to hide your containerPorts. If you really want to, instead of trying to use a secret (which probably isn't possible as its not a security concern), just don't even bother specifying the containerPort in your YAML. Just leave it out. It will still work.